# Using Html.BeginForm with querystring

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.beginform

My url looks like this:

```
customer/login?ReturnUrl=home
```

In the login view, I have used this pattern of code which works fine.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
   ...
}
```

This magically generates following html

```
<form action="customer/login?ReturnUrl=home" method="post">
```

But now, I need to add an attribute (e.g., `data-id="something"`) in the form. How can I do that? If I don't have any query string, I know I can do something like this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(action, controller, FormMethod.Post, 
                      new { data_id="something" }))
```

But don't know how to add querystring which should be in html:

```
<form action="customer/login?ReturnUrl=home" method="post" data-id="something">
```

I thought about using `<form>` directly but don't know how to specify querystring which is variable. And I have no idea how to achieve it with `Html.BeginForm`. Any tip would be appreciated.

**RESOLUTION:**

For now, I used `<form>` with following hint [How to get current url value in View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323707/how-to-get-current-url-value-in-view). The resulting view looks like

```
<form action="@Request.Url.PathAndQuery" data-id="something" method="POST">
```

But it would be nice to have an overloaded method of `BeginForm` for this.

Comment: where are you wanting to add the attribute, to the Form or something in the Form?

Comment: Are you looking to add another form value or to dynamically set the query string?

Comment: @msarchet and Tejs I want the attribute on form element.

Comment: [This][1] will surely help to solve with BeginForm


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076656/asp-net-mvc-html-beginform-and-ssl

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I guess this doesn't directly answer the question, but why not just use a plain old form tag?

```
 <form action='customer/login?ReturnUrl=@Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]' method="post" data-id="something">
```

Alternatively, you can create a custom HtmlHelperExtension that renders a form with path and querystring. In this HtmlHelperExtension you can iterate through your querystring values and populate the routeValueDictionary which you then pass to a Html.BeginForm constructor.

If you don't want something so extensible you can just use the overloaded constructor of  Html.BeginForm using
`@Html.BeginForm("login", "customer", new {ReturnUrl = @Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]},FormMethod.Post, new {data-id="something"});`

Comment: i just noticed you edited your question with the first idea as well.

Comment: But if I add another querystring, I have to change the code again. I got a better answer, please see the last part of my updated answer. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated my answer as well using a constructor of BeginForm itself.

Answer (score 23):

Here's The way that worked for me

```
Html.BeginForm("Profile", "Partner", routeValues: new {id=Partner.partner_id},method:FormMethod.Post)
```

It was almost like there was a problem with overloading the method, but by specifying what things are, it seems to work fine...

Comment: Adding the query string parameters in the routeValues dictionary works for me.

Comment: what if I want to add class to the form as well, @using (Html.BeginForm("actionName", "controllerName", routeValues: new { lang = "en" }, method:FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @class= "my-form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

Answer (score 17):

To create a RouteValueDictionary from the querystring:

```
RouteValueDictionary queryStringDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(Request.QueryString.AllKeys.ToDictionary(key => key, key => (object)Request.QueryString[key]));
```

Then you can use it with Html.BeginForm:

```
Html.BeginForm(null, null, queryStringDictionary, FormMethod.Post, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "autocomplete", "off" } })
```

Answer (score 3):

using Reflector to look at the code,

BeginForm() will pass directly the rawUrl over to the final Form.
Any other overloads on BeginForm will go through a helper utility which will strip the query string.

Answer (score 1):

Just incase you wanted to add other attributes as well. use below code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("actionName", "controllerName", routeValues: new { lang = "en" }, method:FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @class= "my-form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("index", "Photos", routeValues: new { user = pUser, album = pAlbum, }, method: FormMethod.Get))
```

Explicit route values and method is what is required...

Answer (score -1):

Try `@using(Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { data_id="something" }))`

It should use the default logic to construct the url, just as if you used `BeginForm()`

(never tried that though in such case, but I believe it should work)

Comment: I tried that already but resulting form has `action="/customer/login"`. It should be `/customer/login?ReturnUrl=home`

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not preserve the query string when passing null to the action and controller parameters.