# How to get current url value in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, view

I have following Url:

```
customer/login?ReturnUrl=home
```

How can I get this string in my view? I tried

```
RouteData.GetRequiredString("action")
```

But it does not return full string. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the [HttpRequest.Url.PathAndQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.pathandquery.aspx) Property to retrieve the absolute path and query like so:

```
<%= Request.Url.PathAndQuery %>
```